# WHERE AND WHERE NOT in same query mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to use WHERE NOT and WHERE in the same query, I am writing a python script where a function queries a mysql database, I need the script to call a specific name or have it return everyone, and on a side note if I can have it call groups of names that would be even better. I am accomplishing the name query with a simple LIKE statement.

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE column LIKE '%searchterm';
```

However I want to be able to sort the data further using its DATE column, the query I have written for DATE is,

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE NOT (column < startdate OR column > enddate);
```

Both queries work as intended when run on their own, when I try to combine them like so however I get a syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE NOT (column < startdate OR column > enddate) AND WHERE column LIKE '%searchterm';
```

Is there a way to fix the query so that it works?

Comment: change `AND WHERE` to just `AND`

Answer (score 1):

You have one to many where in your query try changing to

```
SELECT * FROM db.table WHERE NOT (column < startdate OR column > enddate) AND column LIKE '%searchterm';
```

Comment: That did it for me. Why is the second WHERE not necessary? It seems counter-intuitive to me that the WHERE NOT doesn't apply across the whole query.

Comment: All the keywords are only once, you set select and list what to select, from and which tables to include and where to set the restrictions. So you have already changed the context to where and only need to specify that your where have another check